# Enumerate through types in Console application from a class library

Tags: c#, .net, dll, console-application, .net-assembly

Initially let's consider the reverse case. If I want to enumerate through all my types in assemblies I have referenced in my console application I can do this

```
var assemblies = Directory.EnumerateFiles(
                     Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), 
                     "MyNamespace.*.dll",
                     SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                .Select(Assembly.LoadFrom)
                .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                .ToList();
```

So straight forward. I need to do the reverse operation. Assuming I am running a Console application and referencing class library `MyClassLibrary`, I would like to get all types in my console application inside a function in `MyClassLibrary`. The issue is console applications don't produce `dll` files and they only output `exe` files. Is there a way to read the types?

Comment: Sure, if you've found the right .exe file, you can load that assembly in exactly the same way.

Comment: I tried it, it did't work. I attempted to read `exe` files instead of `dll` but it wasn't loaded into my assembly array

Comment: Well it *will* work for actual .NET executables. It won't manage to load non-.NET executables. You should edit your question to show what you tried, and what happened. An alternative would be to use `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly`.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are indeed a legend, `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly` is exactly what I was looking for as I only need the `exe` of the executing console app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetTypes();
```

Answer (score 0):

The exe file for a .NET console application is still a .NET assembly. It can be loaded in the same way, but this is somewhat pointless as it is alreadyloaded.

Rather than going through files you can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` to get all loaded assemblies in the current App Domain (and in a console application – unless you create another – there will be only one).